# How to get the right hierarchy level in DAX in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How can I get exact hierarchy level in Power Bi using Dax.

I have a matrix visual something like this--

[image: Matrix table]

I want to have each hierarchy level (year,quarter,month,day) to be displayed Something like this--

[image: Result]

I have tried but I am not getting exact result. My Year level get iterated in every row

[image: My result]

I have written following Dax--

```
hiearchy level = 
IF(
    ISINSCOPE(Date_Master[Date].[Year]),"Y",
    IF(
        ISINSCOPE(Date_Master[Date].[Quarter]),"Q",
        IF(
            ISINSCOPE(Date_Master[Date].[Month]),"M",
            IF(
                ISINSCOPE(Date_Master[Date].[Day]),"D"))))
```

I don't know where I am making mistake.Can someone help me out in this?
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I have got my answer after many trials.
I have used this following Dax

```
Hiearchy = 
var isyearinscope = ISINSCOPE(Date_Master[Date].[Year])
var isquarterinscope = ISINSCOPE(Date_Master[Date].[Quarter])
var ismonthinscope = ISINSCOPE(Date_Master[Date].[Month])
var isdayinscope = ISINSCOPE(Date_Master[Date].[Day])
return
IF(
    isdayinscope,"D",
    IF(
        ismonthinscope,"M",
        IF(
            isquarterinscope,"Q",
            IF(
                isyearinscope,"Y",
                "Y"
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

This is the result I was expecting--

[image: Final result]